# Cypher Question, Return results only if connected with all nodes

Tags: neo4j

The graph bellow shows that two out of three persons have both java and php as skills.
I produced this graph with this query

```
{
 "rows": [
   {
     "name": "PHP",
     "id": 23776,
     "entity_id": 23776,
     "yearsOfExperience": 2
   },
   {
     "name": "Java",
     "id": 17477,
     "entity_id": 17477,
     "yearsOfExperience": 2
   }
 ]
}
```

```
 MATCH  (s:SkillNode) 
 WHERE s.entity_id = row.entity_id
 with s,  row
 match (c:CandidateNode)-[r:KNOWS]->(s)
where r.years_of_experience<=row.yearsOfExperience
RETURN *;
```

What should i change in the query in order to receive Candidates (the greens) only if they have all the skills provided in rows?

For the example i posted, i dont want to have the Candidate "Ena Dyo Tria" but all the others.
"Ena Dyo Tria" user could be in the graph if the rows did not contain PHP .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

> 1. You need to collect all rows and all skills
> 2. Unwind rows as row and check that candidates skills are in all skills you want
> 3. Check that every skill related to this candidate is on the list of ALL skills you want (Java and PHP)

```
 MATCH  (s:SkillNode) 
 WHERE s.entity_id = row.entity_id
 WITH  collect(row) as rows, collect(s) as allSkills
 UNWIND rows as row
 MATCH (c:CandidateNode)-[r:KNOWS]->(s:SkillNode) 
 WHERE r.years_of_experience <= row.yearsOfExperience AND s in allSkills
 WITH c, collect(distinct r) as rels, collect(distinct s) as skills, allSkills 
 WHERE ALL(sk in allSkills where sk in skills) 
 RETURN c, rels, skills

 Sample result:
 ╒════════════════╤═════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════╕
 │"c"             │"rels"       │"skills"                                │
 ╞════════════════╪═════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════╡
 │{"name":"Leo"}  │[{},{},{},{}]│[{"name":"Java"},{"name":"PHP"        }]│
 ├────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │{"name":"Manos"}│[{},{},{},{}]│[{"name":"Java"},{"name":"PHP"        }]│
 └────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you once more for your support and your detailed answer!

Comment: Your welcome @ManosNathanail. Hv a great day!

Comment: Hello again!

After a lot of time i saw that there is something is wrong in this query.
The problem is here r.years_of_experience >= row.yearsOfExperience.

Seems that the query does not compare the years_of_experience for every object in rows.

How is that possible to check if years_of_experience of row item>= years_of_experience of relationship then we want this node, else no!